# Angular Material - Setting custom style for matInput when disabled

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a component with matInput in it as follows:

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 100%;">
<input
                #userInput
                placeholder='search...'
                [formControl]="userInputCtrl"
                [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                title="" [disabled]="disabled">
</mat-form-field>
```

I want to set the background color of the input area to dimgray when its disabled. I've tried the following 2 settings, but it doesn't seem to work. What can I try to resolve this?

```
::ng-deep.mat-form-field-disabled .mat-input-element {
  background-color: #808080 !important;
}
```

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-disabled {
  .mat-input-element {
    background-color: #808080 !important
  }

  .mat-form-field-label {
    background-color: #808080;
  }

  .mat-form-field-underline {
    background-color: #808080;
  }

  .mat-form-field-ripple {
    background-color: #808080;
  }

  .mat-form-field-required-marker {
    background-color: #808080;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you create [a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com)?

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a class dynamically using [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 100%;">
<input
                #userInput
                placeholder='search...'
                [formControl]="userInputCtrl"
                [ngClass]="{'disabled-class: disabled}"
                [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                title=""
                [disabled]="disabled">
</mat-form-field>
```

Edit: Also, you want to avoid using `!important` when it comes to any css. Additionally, `ng-deep` has been [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep). Use global level css when it comes to customizing material styles.

Answer (score 0):

#### Template

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" [class.disabled]="isDisabled">
  <mat-label> Label</mat-label>
  <input matInput required [disabled]="isDisabled" />
  <mat-hint> Hint </mat-hint>
  <mat-error> Errors </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

#### Component TS

```js
 isDisabled = false;
```

#### Style

```
.disabled {
  background-color: gray;
}
```